# Find HTML Element IMG if exists using jQuery?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Currently I have div with a class of `"content"`

Now inside of that div contains multiple images or should I say `<img src="...." alt="....">`

Now I want to hide `<img>` if exists inside of that `content`

Without using `class` or `id`

Here's my sample scenario

```
 <div class="content">
      <img src="...." alt="....">
      <p>Hello World!</p>
      <img src="...." alt="....">
      <img src="...." alt="....">
      <img src="...." alt="....">
      <ul>
         <li>
               Sample
         </li>
         <li>
               Sample
         </li>
      </ul>
 </div>
```

**UPDATE**

Hide the image without using `class` or `id` per specific `img`

Comment: So you want to hide the img without using the class `content` ?

Comment: Sorry, I updated my question

Answer (score 2):

If the class `content` can be used try:

```
$('.content img').hide();
```

**Demo**

```js
$('.content img').hide();
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="content">
      <img src="...." alt="....">
      <p>Hello World!</p>
      <img src="...." alt="....">
      <img src="...." alt="....">
      <img src="...." alt="....">
      <ul>
         <li>
               Sample
         </li>
         <li>
               Sample
         </li>
      </ul>
 </div>
```

If we can't use any class or id, then use:

```
$('p:contains(Hello World!)').siblings('img').hide();
```

**Demo**

```js
$('p:contains(Hello World!)').siblings('img').hide();
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="content">
      <img src="...." alt="....">
      <p>Hello World!</p>
      <img src="...." alt="....">
      <img src="...." alt="....">
      <img src="...." alt="....">
      <ul>
         <li>
               Sample
         </li>
         <li>
               Sample
         </li>
      </ul>
 </div>
```

You can also do it by targeting the `img` using the `onerror` method:

```
<img src="...." alt="...." onError="this.onerror=null;this.style.display='none'" />
```

```html
<div class="content">
      <img src="...." alt="...." onError="this.onerror=null;this.style.display='none'" />
      <img src="...." alt="....">
      <p>Hello World!</p>
      <img src="...." alt="....">
      <img src="...." alt="....">
      <ul>
         <li>
               Sample
         </li>
         <li>
               Sample
         </li>
      </ul>
 </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the **Vanilla JavaScript** approach for your question.

```js
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
  const images = document.querySelectorAll('.content img');
  [...images].forEach(image => image.style.display = 'none');
});
```

```html
<div class="content">
      <img src="...." alt="....">
      <p>Hello World!</p>
      <img src="...." alt="....">
      <img src="...." alt="....">
      <img src="...." alt="....">
      <ul>
         <li>
               Sample
         </li>
         <li>
               Sample
         </li>
      </ul>
 </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
$("p").parent('div.content').children('img').hide();
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="content">
      <img src="...." alt="....">
      <p>Hello World!</p>
      <img src="...." alt="....">
      <img src="...." alt="....">
      <img src="...." alt="....">
      <ul>
         <li>
               Sample
         </li>
         <li>
               Sample
         </li>
      </ul>
 </div>
```

Comment: Why use `p` as the starting selector?

Comment: To check whether that p has the parent div or not so this ocde won't effect other code.